How to install hybrid conky from source
My laptop is a Lenovo E550:
OS:         Arch Linux
KERNEL:     Linux 6.9.6-arch1-1
SHELL:      zsh
CPU:        Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
GPU:        Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500

I want to install hybrid conky. The version on KDE store is buggy so I downloaded the source from bitbucket. I have installed latest version of conky-lua-nv.
I extracted source in ~/.config/conky/hybrid/
Installed fonts via fontmanager system-wide.
Inside the project search for deploy.sh file (for v1.6.0 and above, please use install.sh instead)
using install.sh would wipe the whole conky directory so I tried without it and by deploy.sh script!
Copy content of hybrid.conf from conky directory into ~/.conkyrc
I don't know if I should run deploy.sh or not.According to documentation it should be run for v1.6.0 and above and (I use v1.6.1) so I should use install.sh which will delete conky directory)
Run conky: $ conky -c ~/.config/conky/hybrid/hybrid.conf &
And this is I get: enter image description here
Where am I wrong?

“Where am I wrong?” - You need to run the install script before the deployment script. Just backup your configuration before you install.
